# Is it possible to set a umask/chmod value for docker volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Inside my container I have set umask value to **027** so when ever I create new files it takes `u=rwx g=rx- o=---` but when I create a file inside host it takes the umask value from host. How can I prevent this. I mean how can I force the new files to take the umask value that has been set inside container not from host.

```
version: "3.5"

services:

  php:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}
    build: ./docker/drupal-tools
    image: dbjpanda/drupal-tools
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www/${PROJECT_NAME}
    volumes:
      - drupal:/var/www/example.com
volumes:
  drupal:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/code/drupal
      o: bind
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.  Not only do the container and host have different umasks, but each *process* has its own umask.  For that matter, nothing in **umask**(1) or **umask**(2) suggests that a process can't subsequently change its own umask to something more permissive: it simply isn't a good security or policy-enforcement control.

Comment: So the only way to achieve it is via setfacl ?